# How to get mask to be 100% width of a masked image in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to make use of Mask filter in fabric.js. This is the result I get:
[Incorrectly rendered masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAnmT.png)

First thing is that the mask is pixelated and not rendered correctly (transparent lines). Second thing: how can I make mask image to resize with the image being masked to always be 100% of its width?

Here's my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElement.get(0), {
    clipTo: function (ctx) {
        ctx.rect(relPos.x, relPos.y, dimensions.x, dimensions.y);
    },
    controlsAboveOverlay: true
});

fabric.Image.fromURL(el.options.source, function (img) {
    img.set({
        angle: el.options.degree
    });

    img.set({
        left: el.options.x,
        top: el.options.y,
        width: el.options.width,
        height: el.options.height
    });

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://localhost/mask.jpg', function (maskImg) {
        var mask = new fabric.Image.filters.Mask({mask: maskImg});
        img.filters.push(mask);
        img.applyFilters( function() {
            canvas.add(img);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    });
});
```

I've added this to code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWrbyx .

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: I've posted it just now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to try making it into a working snippet ?

Comment: I've just added this to code pen, but can't get mask filter to render there at all.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work, because the canvas gets tainted as I load data from external domain. Any idea how to do it on codepen?

Comment: Ok, my code pen works now. Any idea how to get the mask to always be 100% width of the image?

Comment: Well done on putting in the effort to get a working example. Often you find the solution as you do this - oh I see you did.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like it works fine on the newest version of Fabric on my environment. And the mask is 100% of the image there. Really weird though why I had those mask rendering problems on older version (1.4.6) on my environment and not on a clean test version on codepen. If anyone has an idea please share a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar discussion with a solution [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2531). Solution seems to be to draw the mask on another canvas same size as the mask image first.